# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando una aplicacion de android que se comunica con la web service para poder agregar datos a mysql. Al ejecutar el codigo, la aplicacion envia algunos datos y espera respuesta del servidor, el servidor se encarga de guardar las imagenes enviadas de la aplicacion en el mismo servidor, enviar otros datos a la BD y devolver respuesta a la aplicacion, pero el servidor solamente consigue guardar las fotos en el servidor y no consigue subir los demas datos a la BD y me devuelve una respuesta de error:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

este es mi codigo php del servidor:

```
 <?PHP
    $hostname_localhost="localhost";
    $database_localhost="photogo";
    $username_localhost="root";
    $password_localhost="Root1234";
    $con=mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);
        $u_name = $_POST["u_name"];
        $localname = $_POST["localname"];
        $zone = $_POST["zone"];
        $category = $_POST["category"];
        $latitude = $_POST["latitude"];
        $logitude = $_POST["longitude"];
        $comment = $_POST["comment"];
        $image = $_POST["image"];
        $date="".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."";
        $name=$u_name."_".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s").".jpg";


        $path = "images/".$name;
        //$url = "http://$hostname_localhost/ejemploBDRemota/$path";
        $url = "images/".$name;
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        $bytesFiles=file_get_contents($path);
        $sql="INSERT INTO dataimage VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $stm=$con->prepare($sql);

        $stm->bind_param('ssssssddss',$bytesFiles,$url,$u_name,$localname,$zone,$category,$latitude,$logitude,$comment,$date);

        if($stm->execute()){
            echo "register";
        }else{
            echo "noRegister";
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Mi BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de android:

```
 public void upLoadToWebService(final ProgressBar progressBar, final String username, String Lname, String Zone, String Category,
                                   final Double Latitude, final  Double Longitude, String Comment, String Image) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Double latitude=Latitude;
        final Double longitude=Longitude;
        final String u_name =username.trim();
        final String localname=Lname.trim();
        final String zone=Zone.trim();
        final String category=Category.trim();
        final String comment=Comment.trim();
        final String image=Image.trim();

        final  String file="/uploadimg/uploadimage.php";
        String url=ip+file;

        strq=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE: ",""+response);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("register")){
                    Toast.makeText(c,"המיקום התווסף בהצלחה", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i =new Intent(c,Principal_Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    ((Activity)c).finish();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(c,"המיקום לא התווסף", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Log.i("ERROR",""+error);
                Toast.makeText(c,"יש בעיה עם התקשורת אנא נסה שנית", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                params.put("u_name",u_name);
                params.put("localname",localname);
                params.put("zone",zone);
                params.put("category",category);
                params.put("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude).trim());
                params.put("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude).trim());
                params.put("comment",comment);
                params.put("image",image);
                return params;
            }
        };

        strq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(c).add(strq);
    }
```

Comment: `$stm` es un boolean. No sera que tienes que hacer `$con->bind_param`

Comment: Ya le encotre la solucion, la columna longitude estaba mal escrita en mi codigo de php, y la tabla Date le cambie el nombre por que al introducir unc consulta on la palabra Date, mysql lo tomaba por un codigo de SQL y no como nombre de tabla